# jQuery changing a color with css :hover

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have the following CSS

```
#button:hover .inner {
    background-color: #9c0000;
    -webkit-animation: circle 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation: circle 1s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: circle 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The idea is that that `.inner` will grow inside the parent div to fill it up. This part works but I would like to allow people to define a `background-color` and when I try `$('#button:hover .inner').css('background-color',colorChoice);` this doesn't change it at all.

So I was wondering is it actually possible to change the `background-color` from the css above using jQuery if I was able to supply a variable such as `var colorChoice = '#ff0';`

I have supplied my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwsDn/2/) to show you how I want it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#button').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.inner').css('background-color',colorChoice);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using jQuery but I think you need to be using http://api.jquery.com/hover/ as opposed to the $('#button:hover .inner') selector you currently have.

Comment: Documentation doesn't mention this, but jQuery Migrate plugin says that `'hover' pseudo-event is deprecated, use 'mouseenter mouseleave'`